# best way to handle workflow call between multiple Spring Boot microservices using central service

Tags: spring-boot

I have to implement 4 microservice in spring boot , spring cloud and there is a central microservices that will handle the workflow between these 4 services like first service call then on response back to central one and then central one will make call to second service and so on . my question is how to implement (best possible way)central microservice avoiding if/else ?

Comment: Ever heard of the [Saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Spring I suggest you have a look at [Spring Statemachine](https://projects.spring.io/spring-statemachine/).

You don't give much details but I think it sounds like it'd be a good fit.